# MikTeX - 64bit vs. 32bit

Tags: comparison

i have a question concerning the difference between the 64bit and 32bit.
Years ago everybody said “use the 32bit, the 64bit is still experimental”, but what changed so far?

My “last” update is that there is no major difference anymore (biber is included, for example), and that you can install the 64bit version on your 64bit system without hesitation. Is that true? Are there still big differences or arguments for or against the one or the other?

Thank you very much!

Comment: [Download of 32-bit or 64-bit Miktex on a 64-bit Pc (Windows 10)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288009)

Comment: Additionally, this is a crosspost to [goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/32bit-vs-64bit-t16670.html) where it was answered days ago.

Comment: Thank you for the link. But it only states that biber is included and that it seems, that there are no differences. I thought I ask, maybe somebody knows more. And of course it is a crosspost, because in the german board the awnser was "most people use the 64bit and have no problem", it wasn't really the answere I was looking for. But thank you again.

Comment: Well, what answer are you looking for? A definite one? You should ask on the MikTeX Mailing list then. As of now, there are no real differences. You can use both, savely.